# what are usage of ping and pong in websocket (starscream)

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, starscream

i'm working on a project which i need to use **Websocket** to exchange data with server

and

i was wondering what is usage of **ping and pong** in Websocket and what are them?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1):

- Ping fired when a ping packet is written out to the server.
- Pong fired when a pong is received from the server.
- for practice & learn socket use this links:
  [enter link description here](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift)
  & [enter link description here](https://medium.com/@spiromifsud/realtime-updates-in-ios-swift-4-using-socket-io-with-mysql-and-node-js-de9ae771529)

Comment: thank you  , but  i wanna work with webSocket not socket.IO (i think they are diffrent .aren't they?). and could you briefly explain why should be use ping and pong ? how can they help us ? @Abbas Torabi

Comment: @Alirezaaj yes there is difference between websocket & socket.io
the difference is:
Its advantages are that it simplifies the usage of WebSockets , and probably more importantly it provides failovers to other protocols in the event that WebSockets are not supported on the browser or server.
& if you wanna use web socket use these librarys:
https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream
https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket

Comment: @Alirezaaj
for ping & pong 
 actually WebSockets implement their own Ping/Pong semantics to keep the connection alive in the absence of any data being sent. This is something you typically have to account for with TCP sockets to ensure the other end hasn’t gone away.

Answer (score 0):

ping and pong is used for checking the websocket connection.
in the way that if the client sends a ping to server and the server doesn't respond with a pong  , the websocket is disconnected.
It's also used to check the speed of data exchange between server and client.